# iPhone MPMoviePlayer hide movie Control

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayer

hi i want hide movie control (Play - next - volume and ..)from MPMoviePlayer ... 
what can i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can do this by this line of code
>   which hides the controls of the
>   player.

```
[player setMovieControlMode:MPMovieControlModeHidden];
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it, but isn't there a setHidden:YES you can do?

Comment: are u mean i write code like this ? 
MPMoviePlayer.setHidden:YES ;  ?

Answer (score 1):

iOS 3.2 and later use "setControlStyle" *e.g.*

```
        [player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the movieControlMode property of MPMoviePlayerController.  You'll probably want MPMovieControlModeHidden.